# Kubernetes, Eucalyptus and A.W.S

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, eucalyptus

I did not find any topic talking about eucalyptus and Kubernetes. And I find that quite weird because eucalyptus allow you to create an hybrid cloud with a private cloud A.W.S. compatible for the S3, EBS and EC2. And, so I was thinking with just Eucalytpus and Kubernetes, you can easily create an awesome hybrid cloud.

Does some experiments Kubernetes with Eucalyptus? If yes, how did you setup it? And, how works your private and public cloud (working together or are they independent)?

Answer (score 0):

Eucalyptus does not yet officially support AWS ECS service, but there has been some work done on this area recently. For that you will have to install Eucalyptus from source using a custom git branch.

The link below explains how to get AWS ECS like service on Eucalyptus,
http://jeevanullas.in/blog/aws-ec2-container-service-api-in-eucalyptus/

Answer (score 0):

We installed Kubernetes on top of Eucalyptus using Rancher. We had to modify the AWS Docker Machine driver to make it work automatically, but a few months ago the ability to use custom regions with Docker Machine so it should be in Rancher soon. You can also install Rancher hosts manually using the bootstrap script.

For the most part, it works quite well and the bonus with using Rancher is you get Swarm, Mesos, and Cattle orchestration engines which increases the types of container deployments. New versions of Rancher to be released will support EBS volumes and we plan to experiment that for container storage.

We haven't tried connecting private and public, but in theory it should work as long as the UDP ports are open required for Rancher networking. But I'm not even sure this is how container orchestration is designed to work multi-region so try with caution.